# Language for automation in cloud Administration or infrastructure management

Tags: python, ruby, automation, cloud, iaas

My question is related to the language to learn for automation task in cloud computing.
will it be python or ruby or some thing else. i want to move into the ladder as a automation engineer for infrastructure in cloud and data centers/companies.

Thanks and Regards,
Your friend.

Comment: There is no good answer to this as it depends on the language(s) chosen at the hosting site. In-house here you'd find Ruby, Perl, Python, Java, C#/.Net, depending on the group and their needs. Expose yourself to many different languages and be functional, then pick up more expertise under fire.

Comment: If you want job security, you could try [Haskell](http://www.haskell.org/) or [Arc](http://arclanguage.org/).

Answer (score 2):

For an interesting Python counterpart to Puppert/Chef see [Ansible](http://ansible.cc/faq.html).

Answer (score 1):

[Chef](http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Home) and [Puppet](http://puppetlabs.com/puppet/what-is-puppet/), two tools commonly used for this kind of automation, are both written in Ruby.

Comment: Adding one more point.But monitoring tools are in python. correct me please if i am wrong. iam little confused about to go to python or to ruby.developing a dashboard in python is little difficult i think so.

Comment: Developing a dashboard can be difficult in any language. It's usually even harder in one you don't know.